# Amendments in Claims and complete Specification

Tags: patentability

I filed a patent from India for National phase. But mistakenly i uploaded a wrong document of claims. As a result i got many flows in First Examination Report regarding my claims. I have applied for PCT where i have uploaded a fresh updated copy of claims and complete specification. I want to upload the PCT claims for my National phase application, but the problem is new claims will cause contradiction with National phase complete specification and drawings. Can i replace the drawings also along with claims?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you filed a national patent in India. You then applied for a PCT application. What is the relationship with the indian national patent application? Did you use this to claim priority?

Comment: What is the nature of the contradiction between the claims and the description? Because it sounds like you're suggesting that your claims are not supported by the description.